# Bind a NSTextField to an object instance method?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have an instance method on an object that spits out a string based on some other objects.  Can I bind this instance method to a field?

Comment: Don't forget to implement `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<ThatMethod>`. Then, any changes that you make to the depended-upon properties in a KVC-compliant way will automatically trigger anything that observes that property—such as the field—to retrieve it again.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSString property, open the nib file and bind a text field's `value` to the property. Then any changes you make to the property will be reflected in the text field.

Comment: You don't have to make it an @property. An instance method, as long as it takes no parameters, will behave equivalently.

Comment: But then you'd have to send out your own KVO notifications, so no, it won't behave equivalently.

Comment: Not true. Try it. Declared as: - (NSString*)value; - (void)setValue:(NSString*)value; and defined as - (NSString*)value { return _value; } - (void)setValue:(NSString*)value { if (![_value isEqualToString: value]) { [_value autorelease]; _value = [value retain]; } }  I sure do get KVO notifications when I set the value.

Comment: Binding *value* to a string-generating method not backed by a property might seem bizarre, but you *can* do it as ipmcc says.   Where it comes in handy is doing something like binding a button *title* to an instance method.  A binding that will never call the setter.  You have have the getter generate an arbitrary string based on the current instance state. The "setter" is empty.   And for any other part of your code to regenerate the displayed string, you'd just have to call the empty setter, and KVO takes care of re-calling the getter.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the getter instance method to the field's value only if you implement a corresponding setter method for the binding to try to write changes in the **value** to.  (No setter needed for some other binding types)

It is okay for the setter to be empty.

For example this is used to display the number of new items across an instance's subtree:

```
- (NSNumber*) numberOfNewItems
{
    NSUInteger total = 0;

    for (childItem* ci in self.items)
        total += (ci.isNewValue) ? ci.items.count : 0;

    return @(total);
}

// Does nothing but allows binding to above to be recalculated
- (void) setNumberOfNewItems:(NSNumber*)number { }
```

That makes a 2-way bindings happy.  If you did not have the setter, you would get errors relating to the keypath not being KVC compliant.  (Unless you are binding to something one-way like "title" or "tool tip" -- those don't need setters.  But the setter comes in handy to get those titles and tooltips recalculated through the getter)

Note that within the childItems, you can then just do this:

```
self.isNewValue = NO;
[self.parent setNumberOfNewItems:nil]; // Trigers KVO for binding (does nothing else)
```

... which is a lot easier than trying to have the parent register as a KVO observer for all the children.

And if you want other properties in the instance to retrigger the getter, you can add this class method:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumberOfNewItems {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"items", @"somethingElse", nil];
}
```